# How do I exclude iPad 2 and iPod Touch 5th Generation in a function?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm trying to create a function that works on ALL iOS devices except the iPad 2 and the iPod Touch 5th Gen.

```
- (void)doSomething {

// if iPad 2 or iPod 5th Gen
if ()
{
    NSLog(@"You're using an iPad 2 or iPod 5th Gen. Sorry!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Any other iOS device. Congrats!");
} }
```

Can someone post a quick sample snippet of how I would accomplish this?

Comment: Apple will probably reject your app for doing that (recommended way is to exclude/include based on available hardware features), but you can get the hardware model number from the sysctl(3) call. Since there's no iPod Touch 5G you'll have to get its model string and you will either only be able to include current, known hardware models (and guesses) or exclude specific known hardware models (e.g., the iPad 2 is iPad2,1 iPad2,2 iPad2,3 for the WiFi, 3G and CDMA models respectively).

Comment: Ok, is there a way to determine if the camera has auto-focus or not?

Comment: Yes, for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Info.plist key, add the auto-focus-camera entry. For a full list of UIKit keys and their definitions, see http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1

Comment: Now that I understand your question, I'll write and answer that I think will make sense.

Answer (score 4):

If your app has a major hardware requirement (i.e., it can't really function/do anything useful if the hardware isn't present on the device), you should add an entry to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` entry in your `Info.plist` for your app. This will keep people who don't have the necessary hardware to use your app from purchasing it/downloading it by accident. It will also cause the App store to show a list of all the models that support your software, so people can see what they need in order to use it.

If your app has a function that requires something specific, there are generally in-framework tests you can do to see if the device has the required features/hardware. If this isn't your app's central purpose, you can then enable/disable this feature of your app based on the device's capabilities. You wouldn't want to try and query which device the user is running (except in maybe very limited circumstances), but would rather query whether the device is capable of doing what you want.

Since you mentioned an auto-focusing camera, we'll use that as an example. If your app requires this to do anything useful, you should add the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key to your `Info.plist` file and add the entry `auto-focus-camera` to the array. This will ensure that only users who have a device with an auto-focusing camera will be able to purchase and install your app. For more information on UIKit keys for `Info.plist`, including this one, see  the [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1).

If, on the other hand, your app is usable by any device but has a feature that requires an auto-focusing camera, you can test for it's presence using the `AVFoundation` framework. You can get what you need here from the [AVCaptureDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520) class. For example, to check if you have access to an auto-focusing camera for video/stills:

```
// Check for the default camera
AVCaptureDevice* camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if( camera && [camera isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus] ) {
  // this device has a default video source capable of autofocus, so enable the feature
} else {
  // this device does not have the required hardware, so disable the feature
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
if ([[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {
   //device with autofocus
}
else {
       //device without autofocus
}
```